# How to compare two data sets in one table using RCode + t.test

Tags: r, statistics

I'm attempting to run a t.test using RCode on some of the sample data you can use from loading the datasets library.

Using the InsectSpray dataset, trying to compare Spray A to Spray C.
My question is, what would be the t.test line of code to compare the two?
The data is originally formatted as a Column Count with the numerical data, and a column Spray which denotes which spray it is, like:
Count: 10 7 8 9... and Spray: A A B B...

Edit: I have already calculated a lot of information and formatted it as:

```
  spray  mean   sd stderr   var
```

`1     A 14.50 4.72   0.39 22.27`

`2     B 15.33 4.27   0.36 18.24`

`3     C  2.08 1.98   0.16  3.90`

`4     D  4.92 2.50   0.21  6.27`

`5     E  3.50 1.73   0.14  3.00`

`6     F 16.67 6.21   0.52 38.61`

Edit2: I have tried to run something like:
`t.test(insect.mn[insect.mn$spray=="A",]$mn, insect.mn[insect.mn$spray=="C",]$mn)`

`Error in t.test.default(insect.mn[insect.mn$spray == "A", ]$mn, insect.mn[insect.mn$spray == : 
not enough 'x' observations`

As far as I can tell, t.test is looking for the actual data sets, not the two means (from my basic understanding of statistics, you can't run a t.test on two means).

Comment: When submitting very simple questions that look like undergarduate homework, You should _at_the_very_least_ post some code to demonstrate that you at least made some effort.

Comment: I attempted to but I must admit, I couldn't figure out how to format it. hah! Actually working on that now.

Comment: At least show that you know how to read the help page by explaining what you don't understand when you do read it. And do run the examples on the help page before posting any further.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. Work with the original data.

Comment: You're right and I apologize for not posting a very complete question the first time.  I've edited in what I've been trying now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the original data. It should be fairly easy to see the next step since you almost got it right with your posted effort:

```
> str(InsectSprays)
'data.frame':   72 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ count: num  10 7 20 14 14 12 10 23 17 20 ...
 $ spray: Factor w/ 6 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> table(InsectSprays[,2])

 A  B  C  D  E  F 
12 12 12 12 12 12 

> InsectSprays[InsectSprays$spray=="A",'count']
 [1] 10  7 20 14 14 12 10 23 17 20 14 13
> InsectSprays[InsectSprays$spray=="C",'count']
 [1] 0 1 7 2 3 1 2 1 3 0 1 4
```